# Twitter search from Jquery not working

Tags: jquery, twitter, salesforce, visualforce

Hi all I am trying to make a simple search for twitter tweets. Its just a basic search but my platform is salesforce and I have made the search url in my remote site setting to but still this code is not working>>

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
$j = jQuery.noConflict();    
function searchTwitter(query) {    
alert(jQuery.param(query));    
    $j.ajax({    
        url: "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=salesforce&rpp=5",    
        dataType: "jsonp",    
        success : function () {    
        alert("Val");    
    }    
});
} 
$j(document).ready(function() {    
$j("#submit").click(function() {    
    var params = {    
        q: $j("#query").val(),    
        rpp: 5    
    };    
    searchTwitter(params);    
});    
});  
</script>   

<div style="padding: 20px;">    
<input id="query" type="text" value="blue angels" />    
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Search" />    
</div>    
<div id="tweets" style="padding: 20px;">    
Tweets will go here.    
</div>
```

But still my call never return the alert("val");. Help

Comment: What you're doing in this code works fine. It's something elsewhere. Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/a78T7/

Comment: hi @DavidKiger may be its salesforce. But i have added this url as exception but still its not working I am also getting the first alert but not the second alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried you code and its working as expected.

First its alerting me a `query-string` and then `alert val`.

What should probably you need to look is.

1. make sure there is only one `DOM` with `id` of submit.
2. use .on instead of .click as $j('#submit').on('click',function(){  });
3. check `jQuery` is already loaded.
4. make sure `jQuery` not conflicting with other java-script library

Comment: @user614946 its working and i get Object { completed_in=

0.052

, max_id=

306633240880496640

, max_id_str=

"306633240880496641"

, more...} as response in console

Comment: I dont know what the problem is but its sure its with salesforce. As there is no conflict between element and dom and jquery is loading properly too.

Comment: @user614946 are you aware of firebug firefox addons..?? if no then use it it will show you all possible errors.

Comment: Yes but what to write that will be capture in fire bug that i dont know??

Comment: console.log to see what are the return value and so on

Comment: Ok I will try that but mean while I got this from : Status (failed) dont know why its getting like this..